# Добрый вечер! У меня ошибка в коде

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyowm

```
from pyowm import OWM
from pyowm.utils import config as cfg
conf=cfg.get_default_config()
conf['language']='ru'
owm = OWM('92cf42d22f7059359433e0c687f1f913',conf)
place = 'Тобольск'
mgr = owm.weather_manager
observation = owm.weather_manager()
w = observation.weather

t = w.temperature("celsius")
t1 = t['temp']
t2 = t['feels_like']
t3 = t['temp_max']
t4 = t['temp_min']
ima = "Джордж"
resuals = 0
resuauls = "o"

print(f"Здравствуйте! Вас приветствует текстовый ассистент {ima}")
print(f"Что вы хотите хотите сделать? Ведь я ассистент {ima}")
a = input("'Посчитай ' 'Погода в раззработке' ")

if a == "Посчитай":
    resuauls = input("+ или -? ")
if resuauls == "+":
    a = int(input("Первое число: " ) )
    b = int(input("Второе число: " ) )
    print(f"Результат: {a + b}")
elif resuauls == "-":
    a = float(input("Первое число: "))
    b = float(input("Второе число: "))
    print(f"Получилось число: {a - b}")
elif a == "Погода":
    resuauls = 0
    print( "Собираю данные..." )
    print(f'В городе {place} темература {t1}')
    print(f'Ощущается как {t2}, максимум будет {t3} градуса')
    print(f'а минимум будет {t4} ')
```

```
t = w.temperature("celsius")
```

NameError: name 'w' is not defined

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (кнопка [edit])

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте заменить

```
mgr = owm.weather_manager
observation = owm.weather_manager()
```

на

```
mgr = owm.weather_manager()
observation = mgr.weather_at_place(place)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! И у меня ещё один маленький вопрос, я скомпельровал .py >> .exe с флагом -F и как мне сделать чтобы программа не закрывалась?

Comment: Поместите код (начиная с первого `print`) в бесконечный цикл `while True`